# Telnet no response using iPhone

Tags: iphone, telnet

My iPhone and desktop are connected to the same wifi. When I use my desktop to telnet to the server I can write the standard commands and get a response, i.e "HELO". When I do the same for my iPhone I get a connection through telnet, but any commands I send I don't get a response.

It was suggested that there may be a delay, but I get a response on desktop in less than 2 seconds. On iPhone I left it for 15 minutes and got nothing.

Also I'm connecting to port 25 on both

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the app I was using didn't use "\r\n" instead it just did "\n". So it wasn't actually pushing the command. Found another app to use in the end.